# Merge three (or more) arrays based on specific index and create new array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have three arrays in which first index is same, so I want to merge all three array into one array based on first index element

Input:

```
[[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C']];
[[1, 'D'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'F']];
[[1, 'G'], [2, 'H'], [3, 'I']];
```

Expected output

```
[ 
  [ 1, 'A', 'D', 'G' ], 
  [ 2, 'B', 'E', 'H' ], 
  [ 3, 'C', 'F', 'I' ] 
]
```

My code:

```
function mergeArrays(arrays) {
  const mergedMap = new Map();

  for (const array of arrays) {
    for (const item of array) {
      const key = item[0];
      if (!mergedMap.has(key)) {
        mergedMap.set(key, [key]);
      }
      mergedMap.get(key).push(...item.slice(1));
    }
  }

  const mergedArray = Array.from(mergedMap.values());

  return mergedArray;
}

const array1 = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C']];
const array2 = [[1, 'D'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'F']];
const array3 = [[1, 'G'], [2, 'H'], [3, 'I']];

const mergedResult = mergeArrays([array1, array2, array3]);
console.log(mergedResult);
```

Would you please suggest any better solution?

Please note: for the simplicity I have make first index as number but in my case it is a Date object.

Answer (score 1):

## shape

```
Expected output

[ 
  [ 1, 'A', 'D', 'G' ], 
  [ 2, 'B', 'E', 'H' ], 
  [ 3, 'C', 'F', 'I' ] 
]
```

I find it slightly surprising that we want lists of [key, val1, val2...]
rather than an object that maps from key to list of values.
But ok, that's what you want, I won't criticize it.

I will say that, as long as we're returning an array,
we might want it to be a sorted array.
That makes it easier to write solid unit tests,
and makes it easier to diff the output when code or data changes.

---

## JSDoc

You offered some very helpful English prose as review context.

Now write some brief documentation comments so that context
won't be lost to future maintainers.

---

## unit tests

Adding an automated test suite to this submission wouldn't hurt.

The `console.log( ... )` is a good first step.
But it requires a human to eyeball the result and assess its correctness.
OTOH automated tests "know the answer"
so they can display Red / Green bars.

---

## unpack

```
      const key = item[0];
      ... .push(...item.slice(1));
```

The {`0`, `1`} subscripts aren't exactly bad but they're unnecessary.

Unpacking with a destructuring assignment would be more convenient:

```
      const [key, val] = item;
      ... .push(val);
```

Notice that this is less powerful than the OP code,
and that's a Good Thing.
The `.slice()` is very flexible, very forgiving,
accommodating zero, two, or more values.
If a buggy input data source or a buggy caller
winds up changing from 2-tuples to something unexpected,
I want to know about it, I *want* a fatal error to
blow up unit tests and any other caller.

---

LGTM, ship it!

Answer (score 1):

> Would you please suggest any better solution?

Maybe different than better possible implementation is using array's `reduce` method twice, once for the array of arrays and once for each of the  contained array...

```
function merge(arrays) {

    var reducer = (accumulator, element, index) => {
       accumulator[index] = accumulator[index].concat(element.slice(1));
       return accumulator;
    };
    
    var reducers = (accumulator, element, index) => {
       if ( index == 0 ) return accumulator;
       element.reduce(reducer, accumulator);
       return accumulator;
    };

    var reducee = arrays || [[]];
    return reducee.reduce(reducers, reducee[0]);
}

var array1 = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'C']];
var array2 = [[1, 'D'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'F']];
var array3 = [[1, 'G'], [2, 'H'], [3, 'I']];
var array4 = [[1, 'J'], [2, 'K'], [3, 'L']];
var array5 = [[1, 'M'], [2, 'N'], [3, 'O']];
var array6 = [[1, 'P'], [2, 'Q'], [3, 'R']];
var array7 = [[1, 'S'], [2, 'T'], [3, 'U']];
var array8 = [[1, 'V'], [2, 'W'], [3, 'X']];
var array9 = [[1, 'Y'], [2, 'Z']];


var merged = merge([ array1, array2, array3
                   , array4, array5, array6
                   , array7, array8, array9 ]);
```